# Asterisk: Join 2 inbound calls

Tags: asterisk

I have a VoIP box setup with Asterisk and using chan_dongle to provide me with an inbound GSM trunk as well as a couple of DID SIP trunks with local numbers. I would like to be able to have the following call-flow:

- Person ring the GSM mobile number, get's a voice prompt to state they should wait.
- I call one of the SIP trunk numbers registered on the PBX as an inbound route.
- The PBX joins the waiting call to the newly established call, so I can now speak to the person who called me.

At some point I would like to add SMS to the mix to send me a message when someone is waiting, but this is phase 2. Can this be done?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1 word... meetme.  It sounds like what you want is a 2-person conference.  With meet-me, you can play a message of your choice... and when the "admin" user connects, the "conference" starts.

Keep in mind that this is not very efficient... but it should work without trouble.

Comment: Yes, but this has a downside that to have an admin PIN but no user PIN, the user gets prompted for a PIN still. Any way around this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue.  If you don't want prompts for a pin... then make the conference pinless.  If you do want an admin user... the system needs some way to identify the user as an admin... so you will need a pin.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could always `park` the call and then setup an extension to automatically answer a parked call.  This could get a bit more tricky if you have multiple calls coming in, and need to answer a specific one.  (You may not know where it is parked)  For a single line, you can simply specify the `PARKINGEXTEN` and then on the context you want to join the two calls... just dial that local exten you defined.